# Multiplication of two vectors in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy

This is something that would be trivial in Fortran, or Basic or even Matlab, but I cannot get it to work in Python + Numpy.  I have tried many of the suggestions and examples but they are too simple to fit this problem.  The pseudocode is as follows:

```
Given a vector a(i) with 500 values. 
for i=1 to 500
    b(i) = some complicated math
    c(i) = a(i) * b(i)
```

How would this be written in Python plus Numpy?

Comment: Are you looking for a [cross product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.cross.html) or a [dot product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)?

Comment: ... or an [element-wise product](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html)?

Comment: @FredLarson judjing by the pseudocode supplied, it would be elementwise (`c(i) = a(i) * b(i)`).

Comment: @Uriel: I believe you're right, which would make the answer `c = numpy.multiply(a, b)`

Comment: You really should show one or more of the failed `Python` tries, and maybe a successful MATLAB one.  As written we don't know what your Python problem is.  It could be a trivial as properly initializing the arrays, or writing the `for` expression.  That `some complicated math` is also a big unknown.  Can it work with arrays, or just scalars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Numpy `multiply` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.multiply.html) to obtain the element-wise vector product. Try something like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(500)
b = 10 * np.arange(500) + 3 # an example of the "complex math"
c = np.multiply(a, b)
```

Note that the mathematical operations (`*` and `+`) are automatically applied to all elements of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on whether the "complicated math" can be vectorized and whether it is one line or several. If it can't be vectorized and takes several lines, which is the more complicated solution, you can do something like this:

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    b[i] = some_complicated_math(ai)
c = a*b
```

In this example, `i` is the current index of `a` and `ai` is the value at that index (the equivalent of `a[i]`).  `enumerate` gives you a value and its (1D) index.  Multiplication in numpy arrays is automatically elementwise.

If the "complicated math" can't be vectorized but can be done on one line, you can do something like this:

```
b = [some_complicated_math(ai) for ai in a]
c = a*b
```

In this case `b` is a list (not a numpy array), but python is smart enough to convert `b` to a numpy array behind-the-scenes since it is being multiplied with the numpy array `a`. You can convert `b` to a numpy array using `np.array(b)` if you need it later.

The simplest scenario is if the "complicated math" can be vectorized. Then you can just do:

```
b = some_complicated_math(a)
c = a*b
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to put `b` and `c` in the loop (the only reason I could think of would be if `b` references `c` somehow), then you can do this:

```
b = np.zeros_like(a)
c = np.zeros_like(a)
for i, ai in enumerate(a):
    b[i] = some_complicated_math(ai)
    c[i] = a[i]*b[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this

```
import numpy as np

n = 500

# Allocate memory for a, b, c
a = np.zeros((n))
b = np.zeros((n))
c = np.zeros((n))

# Loop over element
for i in range(n):
    b[i] = some complicated math
    c[i] = a[i] * b[i]
```